# Rails: Adding a post without refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm new on ruby on rails.

I'm currently working on a facebook clone application and having trouble when adding a post without refreshing the page. Tried to create a post but the post did not show upon submitting and encountered **Internal Server Error**. When the page is refreshed, the newly created post is finally displayed.

*Error in rails server*

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 50ms (ActiveRecord: 15.9ms | Allocations: 10085)



ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):
    1: = form_for([post, @comment]) do |f|
    2:   .form-bottom-button-container
    3:     .d-flex.comment-text-button
    4:       .p-2.flex-grow-1
```

Here are my codes. Please help me out. Thank you very much!

*app/controllers/posts_controller.rb*

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Successfully posted.'}
    else
      format.html { redirect_to posts_path, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

*app/views/posts/create.js.haml*

```
:plain
  $("#post-display").append("#{escape_javascript(render 'post_display', post: @post)}");
```

*app/views/posts/index.html.haml*

```
-# All Posts
.col-8
  .post-form
    = render "post_form"
  - if @posts.empty?
    .post-card
      .post-text
        .no-post-text No posts to show
  - else
    #post-display
      = render partial: "post_display", collection: @posts, as: :post
```

*app/views/posts/_post_display.html.haml*

```
.post-card
  .post-text
    .d-flex.justify-content-between
      .d-flex
        .post-user-image
          - if post.user.profile_pic.present?
            = image_tag post.user.profile_pic.url, class: "img img-fluid img-thumb"
          - else
            = image_tag "/default-user.jpg", class: "img img-fluid img-thumb"
        .d-flex.flex-column
          .username-bold= link_to post.user.username, profile_path(post.user.username)
          .distance-date= distance_of_time_posted_in_words(post.created_at)
      .post-edit-delete
        - if post.user.username == current_user.username
          = link_to edit_post_path(post), class: "text-space", remote: true, "data-bs-toggle" => "modal", "data-bs-target" => "#edit-post-#{post.id}-modal" do
            %i.fa.fa-edit
          .modal.fade(id="edit-post-#{post.id}-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="edit-post-title" aria-hidden="true")
            .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-centered.modal-dialog-scrollable
              .modal-content
          = link_to post, method: :delete, class: "text-space" do
            %i.fa.fa-trash
    .caption= post.caption
  - if post.image.present?
    = image_tag post.image.url, class: "img img-fluid img-fill"

  -# Like Button
  .row.container-margin-top
    .col-6
      - if liker(post)
        = button_to post_like_path(post, liker(post)), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-maroon btn-wide btn-like-comment" do
          %i.far.fa-thumbs-up
          Unlike
      - else
        = button_to post_likes_path(post), method: :post, class: "btn btn-plain btn-wide btn-like-comment" do
          %i.far.fa-thumbs-up
          Like
    .col-6
      .btn.btn-plain.btn-wide.btn-like-comment.btn-comment
        %i.far.fa-comment
        %span Comment

  -# Comment Section
  .comment-box
    .d-flex.justify-content-between
      - unless post.likes.count == 0
        .post-likes(type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#likers-#{post.id}-modal")= "#{pluralize(post.likes.count, "like")}"
        = render "layouts/likers_modal", post: post, index: post.id
      .comment-toggle View Comments
    .comment-display.hidden
      = render "posts/comments", post: post
  .comment-form
    = render "comments/comment_form", post: post
```

*app/views/comments/_comment_form.html.haml*

```
= form_for([post, @comment]) do |f|
  .form-bottom-button-container
    .d-flex.comment-text-button
      .p-2.flex-grow-1
        = f.text_area :content, class: "comment-text-area comment", placeholder: "Write a comment..."
      .p-2
        = f.submit :Comment, class: "btn btn-maroon create-comment-button"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your application logs - it'll probably tell you the `format.js` method does not exist.

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.js # <----
      format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Successfully posted.'}
    else
      format.html { redirect_to posts_path, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Just remove that line or use the `format.json` method and you're good to go.

Comment: I used `format.json` method before and it worked well but the problem is when creating a post, the page will refresh to display the new post. I want my page to display the new post without refreshing the page. Is there other way than the one I did?

Answer (score 0):

To make the page not refresh you must submit the form using ajax request... you simply add remote: true to the form.

```
form_for([post, @comment], remote: true) do |f|
```

Also the error you are getting is because @comment is not being set.

Comment: I see. Errors are now gone when I set `@comment` in my controller. But still, the new post is not displayed even when I put `remote: true` to the form.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs after you post?

Comment: I don't see any errors in my rails server. Also checked console log but it has no error.

Comment: `Rendered posts/_comments.html.haml (Duration: 9.0ms | Allocations: 1679)
  Rendered comments/_comment_form.html.haml (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 231)
  Rendered posts/_post_display.html.haml (Duration: 53.8ms | Allocations: 21307)
  Rendered posts/create.js.haml (Duration: 69.3ms | Allocations: 23944)
Completed 200 OK in 116ms (Views: 78.0ms | ActiveRecord: 15.3ms | Allocations: 30128)`

Comment: Have you checked console logs in your browser? maybe it's a javascript error, do you have jquery installed?

Comment: No error in console logs. Anyway, I already resolved it myself. Fix is to change posts iteration by not using a posts collection. I created `@posts.each` loop and changing the partial into `= render partial: "post_display", locals: { post: post }`. With that, I can now easily prepend a new post through `create.js.haml`.